# Commercial bank holdings of shares and bonds since 2005

Tags: banking

I would like to know how the amount of shares and bonds held by private banks has changed over the past 15 years or so. I dare say the data is available on [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org) (or similar) but I don't know exactly what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out form H8 released by the Fed. You can find the corresponding data on FRED too. For example if you want to check the amount of total securities held by US commercial banks, that’s given by the FRED code: SBCACBW027NBOG. Similarly you can drill down to check specific security types, like US Treasury securities or MBS

Comment: I'm sure that's the right answer and I've given it a plus one - but I'm slightly confused about the phrase "Securities in Bank Credit" why not "securities held by banks" or "securities in bank assets"... why "credit"?

Comment: Because they are a part of bank credit which is made up of securities and loans: https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h8/current/